# Any other way to print on the screen instead of printf() and fprintf() in C?

Tags: c, printf

I'm programming with `gcc` in CentOS 5.5 and the most of time I use `printf()` and `fprintf()` to print on terminal, but in some websites I've seen that some people use `write()`. I want to know if there's other ways to print on terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: You know on some level they are equivalent, and the functions like `printf()` just provide abstractions to help you print and format data easily, and internally call low-level functions like `puts()`. Some operating systems might provide their own functions which may be faster, or have some advantage that the standard library doesn't offer, but that's about it. There aren't a million totally different ways to push characters to a terminal.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output

Answer (score 2):

There are some major differences between these functions.

1. The standard library provides some functions to output to `stdout`: `printf`, `puts`, `putchar` etc.
2. And some functions to output to a stream, you can specify the stream to `stdout`: `fprintf`, `fputs`, `fwrite`, etc.
3. But `write` is different, it's a low-level I/O function. The
   standard library doesn't provide any low-level I/O functions. For
   example, POSIX provides `write` that can output to a file
   descriptor.

Google for how to use each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `puts()` or `putchar()`.

```
puts("Hello, world!\n");
```

There's a also `fputs()`, `putc()`, and `fputc()` if you want/need to specify a `FILE*` to write to.

Answer (score 1):

All the output functions in the C standard I/O library could be used:

- [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html)
- [`fputc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputc.html)
- [`fputs()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputs.html)
- [`fputwc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputwc.html)
- [`fputws()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputws.html)
- [`fwprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwprintf.html)
- [`fwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html)
- [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
- [`putc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putc.html)
- [`putchar()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putchar.html)
- [`puts()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/puts.html)
- [`putwc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putwc.html)
- [`putwchar()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putwchar.html)
- [`vfprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vfprintf.html)
- [`vfwprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vfwprintf.html)
- [`vprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vprintf.html)
- [`vwprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vwprintf.html)
- [`wprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wprintf.html)

Most of the other write-like functions in POSIX could be used (but a few are reserved for sockets and those probably can't be used).

- [`aio_write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/aio_write.html)
- [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html)
- [`putc_unlocked()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putc_unlocked.html)
- [`putchar_unlocked()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putchar_unlocked.html)
- [`pwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html)
- [`vdprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vdprintf.html)
- [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)
- [`writev()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html)

There are many functions in the `curses` library that could be used.