# How can I print in C without using printf?

Tags: c, printing, printf

I am trying to learn on how to Print without using printf function in C.
Could someone please post on what would be the best possible way of doing this?

Comment: `printf` formats the output. Without it, you need to format the output yourself and use simple functions for the printing, for example `fputc`.

Comment: All the other output functions listed in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any other way to print on the screen instead of printf() and fprintf() in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919764/any-other-way-to-print-on-the-screen-instead-of-printf-and-fprintf-in-c)